# When and why converting a Bayesian network into a Markov Random Field?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, markov-random-field

I found many slides and tutorials (e.g., [1,2]) on the probabilistic graphical model introducing the procedure of "converting a Bayesian network (BN) into a Markov random field (MRF) by moralization".

It seems to me that the BN is a more natural way to model the relationship among the variables comparing to that of the MRF.  If one can model the relationship among variables by a BN, why bother converting a BN into a less straightforward MRF?  Are there any advantages of doing so?  When should we convert a BN to an MRF? Thanks.

[1] [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-07/Slides/lecture3-BN&MRF.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eepxing/Class/10708-07/Slides/lecture3-BN&MRF.pdf)

[2] http://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/inference14/slides/lecture2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Checking conditional independencies in MRF, which amounts to graph separation, is relatively simpler than in the BN case where you need to D-separation which may require checking all possible paths to show conditional independence(huge problem with too many variables).
2. Problem with BN's is that there may be cases when you do not know and cannot estimate the actual dependence between your variables. In those cases, introducing independencies introduces a strong bias when modeling the joint distribution, thus it may lead to a difficult learning and prediction problem. On the other hand, MRF builds distributions by joint factors and does not assume any false independencies. The effect of independencies of course grows with the dimensionality of your data. In short, when independencies are not exact, using MRF is a safe choice, but comes with a cost of computing the partition function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I don't think these are valid points.  For 1. if the relationship among three variables A,B,C is v-structured (say A->B<-C), A and C are independent if nothing is given, which cannot be modeled by an MRF. In other words, converting a BN into an MRF mya lose certain independence assumptions.  For 2., I understand certain cases cannot be modeled by a BN.  However, moralization attempts to convert a BN into an MRF, so presumably, the relationship among variables can already be modeled by a BN.  In this case, why do we need to convert a BN into an MRF?  Thanks.